# Bypass Cross Domain Restriction ajax - jquery and or iOS

Tags: html, ios, ajax, xcode, cross-domain

I have an iOS app that loads local HTML via a UIWebView. The HTML is connected to jquery with AJAX. For the HTML, I have a content folder and a container folder. The Content folder has a lot of html files and the container folder has one html file that opens the smaller html's in the container folder in a specific order. The problem is the Container HTML will not load anything from the container folder because of the cross-domain restrictions in AJAX. Is there anything I can add via Xcode that will let me by pass the restrictions or anything I can add the HTML/Jquery that will let me Bypass it? Thanks in advance!

```
         //ReplaceDIV
   function loadInDiv(source)
{
//  alert('start');
    $.ajax({
        url: source,
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data) {$('#content').append(data);},
    });
//  $.get(source, function(data) {
   //   alert(data);
   //   $('#contents').append(data);
   //   });
    //      $(destination).load(source);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove:

`crossDomain: true,`

you should be all set.

Edit:

As I understand it, the task at hand is using ajax to load the contents of one html file to another on the same server. When that is done in a UIWebView from a local resource that would be a localhost request. From the [JQuery Documentation:

> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.

On a localhost request, forcing a cross domain request would break the request causing it to load nothing. Also, as a side note, cross domain requests are incompatible with synchronous requests, which you have set with:

`async: false,`